# Is it possible to add a wildcard CNAME into dnsmasq?

Tags: dnsmasq, hosts

I would like to let the DNS works in round robin way. So I have to put an entry into `/etc/hosts`. However, this does not allow wildcard domains.

Is there any way that I can do this in dnsmasq?

So I will get something like:

```
*.test.example.              0       IN      CNAME   mytest.example.
mytest.example.              0       IN      A       192.0.2.123
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've checked v2.77 and found that wildcard CNAME is working there. You should add to config `cname=*.example.com,default.example.com`, but your dnsmasq should be authoritative server for domain(in this case for example.com). It could be configured according [man](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html). In my case, I have such configuration:

> /etc/hosts
>
> ```
> 127.0.0.1       default.example.com
> 127.0.0.2       default.example.com
> 127.0.0.3       default.example.com
> 127.0.0.4       default.example.com
> 127.0.0.5       default.example.com
> ```
>
> /etc/dnsmasq.conf
>
> ```
> cname=*.example.com,default.example.com
> auth-server=example.com,eth0
> interface-name=example.com,eth0
> auth-zone=example.com,127.0.0.0/24,eth0
> ```

And result:

```
[root@centos-linux ~]# dig @127.0.0.1 *.example.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-29.el7_2.3 <<>> @127.0.0.1 *.example.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 6531
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 6, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;*.example.com.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
*.example.com.      600 IN  CNAME   default.example.com.
default.example.com.    600 IN  A   127.0.0.3
default.example.com.    600 IN  A   127.0.0.4
default.example.com.    600 IN  A   127.0.0.5
default.example.com.    600 IN  A   127.0.0.2
default.example.com.    600 IN  A   127.0.0.1

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Jun 05 16:28:13 MSK 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 155

[root@centos-linux ~]# nslookup 2.example.com 127.0.0.1
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
2.example.com   canonical name = default.example.com.
Name:   default.example.com
Address: 127.0.0.5
Name:   default.example.com
Address: 127.0.0.2
Name:   default.example.com
Address: 127.0.0.3
Name:   default.example.com
Address: 127.0.0.4
Name:   default.example.com
Address: 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: I am aware of `address=` has wildcard. However, `address=` does not do round robin. It does not allow multiple IPs at all.

Comment: @Wang please check update, I found solution for `dnsmasq v2.77`

Comment: Thanks! WoW, just saw the change log, I am so lucky! Would you please remove the part in your answer before your update? It is apparently  irrelevant.

Comment: This is completely the wrong answer. A DNS record which resolves the literal query "*.domain.com" is not a wildcard record. This is a bad DNS record for a single domain called "*.domain.com" There seems to be some confusion in the DNSmasq documentation about this, as the author calls this out in his docs. The syntax "address=/domain.com/1.1.1.1" *does* create a wildcard domain, but only for a single IP. FWIW the wildcard form of the above question should resolve *any* sub-domain of example.com to the same address(es), but it does not.

Comment: just to clarify the above comment lost to formatting the asterisk as italics, this answer does not create a wildcard, it creates a record for a literal asterisk.example.com `*.example.com` CNAME to `example.com` which is not useful at all

Comment: @JeffPuckett I'm read documentation wrong? `--cname as long as the record name is in the authoritative domain. If the target of the CNAME is unqualified, then it is qualified with the authoritative zone name. CNAME used in this way (only) may be wildcards, as in --cname=*.example.com,default.example.com`. According this part, this only one way to create wildcard domain in `dnsmasq`.

Comment: How would I create a wildcard CNAME that points to another domain, i.e. `cname=*.example,default.exmaple2`?